# No se acomoda como se desea el Fondo/Background generando espacio blanco

Tags: bootstrap, css3

La siguiente es una captura de mi sitio:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Como se aprecia la imagen no ocupa todo el fondo y genera un espacio en blanco, porque agregué la propiedad `CSS3` :

```
background-repeat: no-repeat;
```

Debí **añadir dicha propiedad** porque cuando adaptaba la pagina a móvil, se **duplicaba la imagen de fondo** y no es ese el resultado que deseo.

El `framework` con el que estoy trabajando es `bootstrap version 3.3.7`.

Este es el código `CSS` del body:

```
body {
    background-image: url("img/imgoriginales/seccionsementales.jpg");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
               }
```

**NUEVA EDICIÓN DE LA PREGUNTA:**

Agrego el código utilizado en base a una respuesta de un usuario:

```
    body {
        background-image: url("img/imgoriginales/seccionsementales.jpg") ;
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        background-size: cover;   
}
```

Me genera entonces otro espacio abajo de la web :

[image: Este es el error]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para escalar la imagen de fondo para cubrir todo, intenta:

```
body{
   background-image: url("img/imgoriginales/seccionsementales.jpg");
   -webkit-background-size: cover;
   -moz-background-size: cover;
   -o-background-size: cover;
   background-size: cover !important; /* !important es opcional para forzarlo */
   background-repeat:no-repeat !important;
}
```

Para escalar la imagen de fondo para caber dentro del body, intenta:

```
body{
   background-image: url("img/imgoriginales/seccionsementales.jpg");
   -webkit-background-size: contain;
   -moz-background-size: contain;
   -o-background-size: contain;
   background-size: contain !important;
   background-repeat:no-repeat !important;
}
```

Otra opción puede ser:

```
body{
   background-image: url("img/imgoriginales/seccionsementales.jpg");
   -webkit-background-size: 100% 100%;
   -moz-background-size: 100% 100%;
   -o-background-size: 100% 100%;
   background-size: 100% 100% !important;
   background-repeat:no-repeat !important;
}
```

---

De esta manera no repite el fondo y cubre la totalidad del espacio disponible.

Comment: mm funciono pero ahotra me lo crea abajo :( hare otra pregunta acerca de eso.

Comment: puedes editar [esta misma pregunta aquí](https://es.stackoverflow.com/posts/81951/edit) añadiendo los datos extra del nuevo funcionamiento

Comment: @gilbertoquintero no hagas otra pregunta, con el comentario es suficiente para que Rene modifique su respuesta.

Comment: Gracias me ayudastes mucho con tu respuesta.

Comment: Excelente!!! :)

Answer (score 1):

En tu css

```
body {background: url(tuimagen.jpg) center center cover fixed no-repeat;}
```

Comment: me la desaparece ?

Comment: ¿Acaso has copiado el código sin reemplazar **"tuimagen.jpg"** por `img/imgoriginales/seccionsementales.jpg`?

Comment: background-image:

Comment: si ajajaajaja ya la cambie y me funciona ups no me di cuenta de eso.

Answer (score -1):

Cambie el valor de `background-repeat`.

Usa `round;`

Asi:

```
background-repeat: round;
```

Answer (score -1):

Viendo mi propio codigo y el codigo de otro usuario aqui estan las dos soluciones:

del usuario:

```css
 /* -webkit-background-size: 150% 200%;
   -moz-background-size: 150% 200%;
   -o-background-size: 150% 200%;
   background-size: 150% 200%;*/
```

Solo modifique los % de cada propiedad.

Mi solucion que encontre:

```css
   background-size:100% 100%;
    background-attachment:fixed;
```